# CGLIB Byte code generation for AspectJ

Tags: java, spring, aspectj

How do I view the CGLib generated bytecode proxies so that I can understand the internals of AspectJ?

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to look at AspectJ? In any case , check out javassist, IIRC it has a class loader that can help. I think.

Comment: AspectJ does not use CGLib.  It uses bcel to generate the byte code.  There are no proxies.  Only spring aspects use CGLib

Answer (score 1):

Regardless of whatever bytecode you wish to see. I would suggest you use a decompiler.

[JD-GUI](http://java.decompiler.free.fr/?q=jdgui) and its counterpart the [JD-Eclipse](http://java.decompiler.free.fr/jd-eclipse/update) (eclipse plugin update site) are great!

I use them to view aspectJ's weaved code.

if the above links don't work (as they seemed not to, for me today) you can use the below:

http://www.softpedia.com/get/Programming/Debuggers-Decompilers-Dissasemblers/JD-GUI.shtml